# Working with multiple jQuery libraries and Prototype

Tags: prototypejs, jquery

Ok, i saw some other posts about this sort of thing, but not exactly related.
This is not what I want to do, but need to do unfortunately.

We have in this order right now
Prototype 1.6
jQuery 1.2.6 with noConflict on jQuery with j

I need to add jQuery 1.4.2 in that mix as well. It will always be the last one loaded. No option.

Is there anyway i can do this currently?

I know this is not good, yada, yada, but it has to be done for now unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand how the order works unless of you have a loop waiting for the load, because I think the script includes are asynchronous.

You can have Prototype and jquery coexit if in jquery you safely wrap your jquery code in a:

```
(function($){

   //jQuery goodness

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the answers to this question will help you.  It seems to be a similar situation.

[Is it possible to load multiple different version of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613808/is-it-possible-to-load-multiple-different-version-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

The order they are on the page is how they will be loaded, however making sure they don't conflict and demolish eachother is a completely different ballgame.

Whatever situation is causing this, you might want to just start from scratch.

Comment: well we have a big site that was built with Prototype, then started migrating to jq 1.2.3. not everything has been converted from PT to jQ yet. I need the jsTree plugin that uses 1.4.2, but some older plugins for whatever reason are failing on it.

Comment: I'm not recommending this... but you could try to extract the applicable methods from the earlier version and host them in another file to gain access to the stuff you need. This might cause more grief then it's worth though :(